# Can't run pip after updating Python

Tags: python, pip

I wanted to setup a program using pip in my PC but it kept returning the same error message when I try install the `requirements.txt`.

I had a Python 3.9 installation on my PC. I upgraded it to Python 3.11. Now when I run pip it returns this error:

> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe"  "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" install -r requirements.txt ': The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/ -- Probably something went wrong. If I were you, I would carefully uninstall all Python installations, and reinstall Python from scratch (if possible prefer the installer downloaded from `python.org` instead of the Windows Store).

Comment: Have you checked PATH variable in system settings?

Comment: The Python installer doesn't have the ability to upgrade 3.9 to 3.11.  If you ran the 3.11 installer but somehow convinced it to install/upgrade to the `Python39` folder, then your installation is fubar and you can only delete everything and start over.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Lesiak I checked the path variables and everything looks normal.

Comment: @AndersMunch I reinstalled like you suggested and thank you everything works fine now.